# How to output values of a custom type using NSLog?

Tags: typedef, eigen, objective-c++, nslog

**Background**

I'm using [VES](https://github.com/aashish24/ves) to leverage the Kiwi point cloud viewer on iOS devices.

**Error**

```
vesVector3f v = self->mKiwiApp->cameraFocalPoint();
NSLog(@"%@",  v);
```

*results in*

```
Cannot pass non-POD object of type `vesVector3f` (aka 'Matrix<float, 3, 1>') to variadic function; expected type from format string was 'id'
```

**Question**

I understand that `NSLog` is expected to output an object of type `id`. How do I get `NSLog` to output type `vesVector3f` ?

*Extra Details*

Here are some details I found about the custom type. It appears `Vector3f` is a vector of 3 floats.

- `typedef Eigen::Vector3f vesVector3f;`
- `EIGEN_MAKE_TYPEDEFS_ALL_SIZES(float, f)`

## Solution

Per `trojanfoe`'s comment:

```
NSLog(@"%f, %f, %f", v(0, 0), v(1, 0), v(2, 0));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like Objective-C++ given [Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixClass.html) is a C++ library.

You'll want to print each of the float member variables something like this:

```
NSLog(@"%f, %f, %f", v(0, 0), v(1, 0), v(2, 0));
```

I say "something like this" as I've never used Eigen.

You can only use `%@` with an Objective-C class, where you would override the `description` method in order for it to work to your liking.

Comment: I didn't know "Objective-C++" was a term but yes, it is definitely that. This gave me a `SIGABRT` initially but after flipping the params inside `v(n, m)` I was able to get the values I was looking for.

Comment: @Jacksonkr Cheers; flipped arguments in my answer for future visitors.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I get NSLog to output type vesVector3f ?

It would need to be an object, as the error message tells you. If it's a struct, it cannot be output directly via NSLog. You could output the three floats yourself, individually. But if you are going to be doing this a lot, you could, for example, write a routine that converts the three floats to a string and output that string. That is what built-in routines like [NSStringFromCGVector](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/#//apple_ref/c/func/NSStringFromCGVector) do.